# How do I deal with reflections inside an ellipse?

Tags: geometry, physics, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, reflection

Suppose I have an ellipse with foci $F_1$ and $F_2$. How do I show that any ray of light which intersects the segment connecting the foci will have subsequent reflections that always are tangent to the/a hyperbola formed with the same foci?

Comment: This is an interesting problem. I've been trying to approach it with a bit of analytic geometry, a little calculus, and a lot of trig, but I haven't made much progress. Could you tell us where you got the problem, and what tools might be expected in its solution?

Comment: @yashg: Once you have a line passing between the two foci, there is definitely a unique confocal hyperbola that is tangent to that line. Presumably, the same hyperbola arises for all lines determined by the various reflections of the light ray. In my own work, formulations of the hyperbola and the reflected lines have been pretty ugly, with no clear connection. The key would seem to be finding a particularly-convenient representation of the curves. Perhaps there's an elegant geometric argument, but without helpful context from OP, it's hard to guess if that's an avenue worth exploring.

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure what tools are expected to use this for this problem, I realized it was true when I was reading about this: http://poncelet.math.nthu.edu.tw/disk5/summer00/029/new_page_59.htm  so maybe it has to to with poncelet porism?  I'm completely new to any curve not involving a circle of some sort in euclidean geometry.  So I really have no idea what kinds of techniques are used.  Should I change the problem to "tangent to some hyperbola" instead of "tangent to the hyperbola"?

Answer (score 5):

Here's an interesting observation that fell out of my calculations: a "construction" of the tangent hyperbola (or ellipse) for a given chord.

[image]

Let $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ be an extended chord of ellipse $ABCD$ passing between the foci, and let $P$ be the *pole* of $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ (that is, the intersection of the tangents at $A$ and $B$). Drop a perpendicular from $P$ onto $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ at $F$. Then the confocal hyperbola through $F$ is tangent to $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ there.

(When the chord (see $\overleftrightarrow{CD}$) doesn't pass through the foci, dropping a perpendicular from the pole ($Q$) gives the point ($G$) of tangency on the confocal ellipse tangent to the chord.)

For proof, one can do what I did: slog through trigonometric simplifications based on the standard parameterization of the ellipse, using the fact that the tangent vector to point $(a\cos\theta, b\sin\theta)$ is $(-a\sin\theta,b\cos\theta)$. (A computer algebra system like *Mathematica* really helps here!) One could also seek a more-satisfying geometric argument.

This observation reduces the original problem to showing that consecutive segments in a reflection path (say, $BAB^\prime$) give rise to points ($F$ and $F^\prime$) on the same hyperbola.

[image]

Again, an arduous trigonometric-coordinate argument will do the trick. Tantalizingly, the poles ($P$ and $P^\prime$) in this scenario both lie on the tangent at $A$, and by the reflection property, we have $\triangle APF\sim\triangle AP^\prime F^\prime$. As mentioned in my comment to @ChristianBlatter's answer, Serge Tabachnikov's ["Geometry and Billiards"](http://www.math.psu.edu/tabachni/Books/billiardsgeometry.pdf) has a concise geometric proof; even so, the above may lead to a not-unreasonable alternative.

---

**Edit.** I've been playing with this a bit more, and found the following:

> Let the ellipse have focal radius $c$ and major radius $a$ (and minor radius $b := \sqrt{a^2-c^2}$). Using the standard parameterization $E(\theta) = (a\cos\theta, b\sin\theta)$, take chord $\overline{AB}$ to have endpoints $A=E(2\alpha)$ and $B=E(2\beta)$. Let $d$ be the transverse/major radius of the confocal conic tangent to $\overline{AB}$ (according as the conic is a hyperbola/ellipse). Then,
>   $$\frac{d^2}{a^2} = \frac{ a^2 - c^2 \cos^2(\alpha+\beta) }{ a^2 \cos^2(\alpha-\beta) - c^2 \cos 2\alpha \cos 2\beta } \qquad (\star)$$

That all chords of a light path are tangent to a particular confocal conic implies that the left-hand side of $(\star)$ ---and therefore also the right-hand side--- **is constant over all chords of the light path**.

We can improve $(\star)$ a bit by re-parameterizing the ellipse as a polar graph with a focus at the origin:
$$r(\phi) = \frac{a^2-c^2}{a-c\cos\phi}$$
Here, we write $A = r(2\alpha^\star)$ and $B = r(2\beta^\star)$, and get

> $$\frac{d^2}{a^2} =  
> \frac{ c^2 - 2 a c \cos(\alpha^\star - \beta^\star) \cos(\alpha^\star + \beta^\star) + a^2 \cos^2(\alpha^\star - \beta^\star) }{ a^2 - 2 a c \cos(\alpha^\star - \beta^\star) \cos(\alpha^\star + \beta^\star)  + c^2 \cos^2(\alpha^\star - \beta^\star)  } \qquad(\star\star)$$

While $(\star\star)$ is longer than $(\star)$, it has more symmetry. Moreover, its geometric meaning is more clear:

- The numerator is the square of the length of the side of a triangle whose other sides, of length $c$ and $a\cos(\alpha^\star - \beta^\star)$, enclose an angle of measure $\alpha^\star + \beta^\star$.
- The denominator is the square of the length of the side of a triangle whose other sides, of length $a$ and $c\cos(\alpha^\star - \beta^\star)$, enclose an angle of measure $\alpha^\star + \beta^\star$.

One can readily construct representative segments based on the bisector of $\angle AOB$, although I personally can't "see" (yet?) in the construction why the ratio of their lengths should be a light-path constant.

Anyway, this result is probably well-known in the vast elliptical-billiards literature, but I didn't happen to come across it with a cursory scan of Tabachnikov's article, so I thought I'd share.

Answer (score 4):

Elliptical billards are a classical topic. For a quick introduction see:

*Billiards*, by Serge Tabachnikov; Panoramas et Synthèses 1, SMF, Paris 1995 (in English),

p. 28ff., in particular  Corollary 2.3.4 on p. 32.

Comment: Based on that lead, I found Tabachnikov's more-recent (2005)  ["Geometry and Billiards" (PDF)](http://www.math.psu.edu/tabachni/Books/billiardsgeometry.pdf). OP's question corresponds to Theorem 4.4(1) on page 54. The geometric proof is only a few short paragraphs, although I haven't done more than scan it at this point.

Comment: Wow thanks.  I will check it out!