# Is there an elementary proof for the envelope of an infinitely-bouncing billiard ball?

Tags: billiards

I was reading this page here

http://cage.ugent.be/~hs/billiards/billiards.html

And was wondering if there existed an elementary proof of proving that the envelopes form certain conic sections (ie: hyperbola or ellipse) depending on the initial angle of projection. It seems like a fascinating topic that I'd like to dig deeper into.

Comment: Related Question: ["How do I deal with reflections inside an ellipse?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1134550/409)